# Check if All Tiles/Features loaded in polygon/Boundary in MapBOX

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, feature-extraction, turfjs

I am new to Mapbox. I am getting trouble while reading the features. I am only able to get the features which are listed or shown on current Viewport. I need to ask if there is any event in mapbox to check if all tiles/Features loaded inside my selected polygon so I can read all features between polygon. The code I am using for reading features is

```
map.on("idle", () => {
 var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(
        [northEastPointPixel, southWestPointPixel],
        {
          layers: ["MyLayer"],
        }
      );
    });
```